highlight mouse pointer in desktop debian 12 issue (openbox window manager)
so i have a problem, that is highlighting the mouse pointer for my screencasts/recordings but the problem is the mouse pointer highlight from key-mon isn't click through. So it basically doesn't allow me to click anything when the mouse pointer is highlighted
screencast for refrence (link disappears or gets taken by someone else after 18 hours):
https://www.dro.pm/ea

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

my problem is that the highlight by key-mon with the --follow_mouse option isn't clickthourgh so i cant click on anything with the key-mon mouse pointer highlighting, please look at the screencast in https://www.dro.pm/ea, please help me
